# bibliograpy (chapterbib) produces a [?] where the citation should be

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

first to all sorry for my english, isn´t me native language and is difficult for me. It´s the first time that i use this forum for that reason.

Now, i´ll try to explain my problem. I need to do multiple bibliographies, one for each chapter, and for it i´m using the package `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` (I'm using TexnicCenter), and using a file .bib  for each one of them.

After to compilate, in the end of each chapter appears the respective bibliograpy, but in the part of the text where's the cite `(\cite{....})`, in pdf file (Latex=>PDF) appears [?], even after two or three compilations.

Is the first time that i have this problem, but also is the first time that use `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}`, so think that the problem is there, although the bibliographies are created in each chapter after compilation, means that files .bib are ok and to use `\usepackage[sectionbib]{chapterbib}` would be right, so i don´t know where is my mistake

Comment: How many times have you compiled the document?  Take a look at this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/204840/problems-with-the-apacite-package#comment478684_204840

Comment: have you run bibtex? the command sequence has to be latex (or pdflatex), bibtex, latex, latex. The first run of latex just collects the used `\cite` then bibtex generates the bibliography from the .bib file using the list of \cite, then you need to run latex again to include the generated bibliography